# perf bewteen std::execution::unseq and std::execution::seq

Tags: c++, performance

I'm playing with c++ execution policy in MSVC (c++20 with O2 and AVX2).
I'm not able to create a case where `std::execution::unseq` executes faster than `std::execution::seq`.

Does someone has an example ?

Comment: Your compiler may be smart enough to already vectorize for "seq". Have you checked the assembly generated for both cases?

Comment: Theoretically, an implementation could be able to vectorize the code. In practice, I am not aware of any implementation actually doing that (AFAIK neither Clang, nor GCC, nor even MSVC do that). If your functor is non trivial, there is no change on mainstream compiler for this to be vectorized. I do not expect this to change soon. It might be different on special compilers (e.g. targetting GPUs)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm just looking for a case where unseq gives better performance than seq. looking at the assembly is not helping in my quest.